# c++ : run a simple code using Dev-c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I have this error message even when I run  a simple code in Dev-C++ , Please help me figure things out !.

```
// Demonstration of variables
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
 unsigned short int Width = 5, Length;
 Length = 10;

 // create an unsigned short and initialize with result
 // of multiplying Width by Length
 unsigned short int Area = Width * Length;

 cout << "Width:" << Width << "\n";
 cout << "Length: " << Length << endl;
 cout << "Area: " << Area << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

here is the error message :

```
C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe  cannot open output file C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin\area.exe: Permission denied
C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin\area.exe` UAC will prevent you from putting files in C:\Program Files. It seems your output folder is wrong.

Comment: There are often UAC issues when you try to write anywhere inside C:\Program Files. Try changing your output folder to some other location. For example, a folder under My Documents is usually good.

Comment: I don't imagine you really want all of your programs to be squished into the same folder as the compiler itself, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your project in a more appropriate location, like "My Documents". "Program Files" is for, well, program files. Your operating system will not let you create new applications there like this. It's a security violation.

Comment: inb4 yes I know he's creating a program file